How can I access the logo creation tools in GIMP?
Where is the extension menu in gimp 2.6 for windows?, over a decade ago, asked where to go to get GIMP's logo creation facilities.
Its answer no longer holds, File -> Create has no option to create a logo, and searching through the menus nothing looked promising.
How can I create logos via Gimp 2.10.30 under Mint Virginia?
--UPDATE--
In response to the first comment on the question, let me include a screenshot, representing Gimp 2.8.x. My question was not about whether in a broad sense one can use GIMP to create a graphics logo. It was about whether specific logo-oriented tools in past versions of GIMP were still available. From a screenshot:


I'm not sure what you're expecting. "File -> Create" implies this is only an image size (pixels) preset. Why not just specify the size manually!? What's your definition of a "logo"?

Is there a specific Extension you were/are using that is supposed to create/add this menu?

No; it was plain vanilla GIMP as installed with Linux Mint 18.2.

@music2myear I remember this set of options being available in older versions of GIMP for as far as I can remember. No add-ons needed as far as I can remember.

I think these are considered addons/plugins/extensions, I'm not sure why they stopped being bundled with a stock install but it looks like they are still available for download over here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp-data-extras/
for example, "Frosty" is this script, and if installed it would add the menu item "/File/Create/Logos":
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp-data-extras/-/blob/master/scripts/frosty-logo.scm?ref_type=heads
Download Link:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp-data-extras/-/archive/master/gimp-data-extras-master.zip
Notes on Installing from Docs:
https://docs.gimp.org/en/install-script-fu.html
Mention opening Edit -> Preferences -> Folders -> Scripts, scripts can be extracted to this folder, then gimp restarted or "Scripts Reloaded" under Tools Menu.

On Debian'ish distributions you may like the apt-get install gimp-data-extras package.
